# Why is $\neg(P\land Q)$ equivalent to $\neg P\lor\neg Q$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Why is $\neg(P\land Q)$ equivalent to $\neg P\lor\neg Q$, and how do we prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: Write down the truth tables and compare them.

Comment: If you search for `De Morgan's laws`, you'll find ample questions that discuss this.

Comment: If you want a proof without using truth table you can define a function $v(P)$ that is called truth value. if $P$ is true then $v(P)=1$ and if $P$ is false then $v(P)=0$.
Then following formula in logic is true. 
$$v(\neg P)=1-v(P)$$
$$v(P\land Q)=v(P)v(Q)$$
$$v(P\lor Q)=v(P)+v(Q)-v(P)v(Q)$$
Now if you use above formulas you can see that 
$$v(\neg(P\land Q))=v(\neg P\lor\neg Q)=1-v(P)v(Q).$$

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have the following acts in logic:
∧:Conjugation
∨:Divorcement
¬ :Negation

In Boolean Calculus there also the following:

$\bigoplus$:either(where  we have true or 1 only if one of the operators in the act is true ,e.x $0 \bigoplus 0=0$, $0 \bigoplus 1=1$, $1 \bigoplus 0=1$, $1 \bigoplus 1=0$.

$<->$:which is the equality

$->$:implication.

All these Boolean acts can be described with the non boolean ones like:

$P∨Q$=$¬(¬P∧¬Q)$

$P->Q$=$¬P∨Q$

$P<->Q$=$(P->Q)∧(Q->P)$

$P \bigoplus Q$=$¬(P<->Q)$

Now a main tool for these things is the distributive property.

With all these you can get minimal forms.

Now for the $¬(P∧Q)=¬P∨¬Q$

When you use $¬$ in front of a bracket it acts on every operators in the bracket.So the $∧$ becomes $∨$ and everything that has $¬$ then doesn't because $¬(¬P)=P$,because if you say no to no then it's yes!

Comment: many thanks for your help, sorry for the miss leading i want the  Proof of the De Morgan's laws in implication